# Como alocar um projeto Python (Django) em um servidor pronto e configurado? (Apache, MySQL, Python, Django OK)

Tags: python, apache, aplicação-web, django

Possuo um servidor pronto e totalmente configurado.
Python, Django, Apache, MySQL, tudo OK.

Gostaria de replicar um projeto já existente neste servidor para testes.
Os arquivos e banco de dados já estão replicados, porém, ao acessar a pasta do projeto via navegador ele trás os diretórios sem interpretar os códigos em Python, como abaixo:

```
cgi-bin/
robots.txt
wsgi.py
Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.9 mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at test.xxxxxx.com.br Port 80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muitas coisas depende de onde vc vai implantar o projeto.

Se as configurações são estas que estão ai "Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.9 mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at test.xxxxxx.com.br Port 80"

Esperimente esse tutorial aqui:

https://gist.github.com/douglasmiranda/1232693